# org.gradle.execution.TaskSelectionException: Task 'wrapper' not found in project ':app'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-build, android-gradle-3.0

I open my project after a few days and I started getting this error

```
org.gradle.execution.TaskSelectionException: Task 'wrapper' not found in project ':app'.
```

I tried to `Clean Project and Invalidate Caches/Restart` option But still no luck.

project level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
        classpath 'org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.2.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'org.greenrobot.greendao'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.seeken.pomodoro"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-beta04'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta01'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:greendao:3.2.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

I am using Android Studio 3.5.1 if it is relevant information.

Comment: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0'`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya did not work. still the same issue.

Comment: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/`??

Comment: I changed to 5.6.4

Comment: Then clean-Rebuild-Restart ide

Comment: if same issue coming then upgrade AS to `3.6.1`

Comment: Now it's giving me new error `Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle: .
Searched in the following locations:`

Comment: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'`

Comment: I changed to 3.6.1. Now I am getting the same old error
`Task 'wrapper' not found in project ':app'.` I also clean and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What worked for me was to add this line to the project-level build.gradle (i.e. not the top-level `android` one, the inner `app` one):

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '6.7.1'
}
```

The gradle version of course depends on what currently the latest one is.

I then got a different error message about the `prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel` missing and had to add this line as well:

```
task prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel {
}
```